# Python regular expressions repeated sequence of decimal number followed by whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

A quick quiz, should be a no brainer:

I want to be able to match strings of the following kind :

`1323 323    434`

i.e. a decimal number, followed by some white space and this repeated as many times as needed. I tried the folowing:

`re1 = re.compile(r"(\d+\s+)+")`

But on the string given, `re1.findall("1323 323    434 ")` returns

`['434']`, while I want it to return `['1323 ','323    ','434 ']` or even just the numbers without the whitespaces

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're repeating the capturing group, and each repetition overwrites the previous sub-match.

If you only want to find numbers that are followed by a whitespace character, you can use

```
re.findall(r"\d+(?=\s)", "1323 323 434 ")
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the last `+`:

```
>>> re1 = re.compile(r"(\d+\s+)")
>>> re1.findall("1323 323 434 ")
['1323 ', '323 ', '434 ']
#Without spaces:
>>> re1 = re.compile(r"(\d+)\s+")
>>> re1.findall("1323 323 434 ")
['1323', '323', '434']
```